# error in plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
create function dept_count (dept_name varchar(20))
returns integer as $$
begin
declare d_count integer;
select count(*) into d_count
from instructor;
return d_count; end; 
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This is my code. This gives an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 5: select count(*) into d_count
               ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "count(*) into d_count from instructor"
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

[`DECLARE` must come before `BEGIN`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html)

Otherwise your function would work - except that it doesn't make much sense to declare a parameter that is not referenced, but that's probably just a simplification for the purpose of this question.